# Change styled-component styling based on window.pageYOffset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

So I have component that I would like to change the styling of based on the `window.pageYOffset` value. When the user scrolls down X value, I would like to change the background color, although this should not be limited to just the background color as I may also want to change other properties, such as the `font-size`, `color`, `padding` and so forth.

Here's what I currently have.

```
const AppHeader: React.FC = () => {
  const [scrollY, setScrollY] = React.useState('')

  function handleScroll() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 1) {
      // Be able to change styling properties based on true / false.
    }
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <Header>
      <h1>Header!</h1>
    </Header>
  )
}

const Header = styled.header`
  // Somehow change the backgound color if window.pageYOffset is greater than value.
  background: ${({color}) => color ? "red" : "blue"};
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
`
```

Here's a [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-margulis-pru9o?file=/src/App.tsx:95-690), forks are appretiated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the scroll offset:

```
function handleScroll() {
  setScrollY(window.pageYOffset);
}
```

Pass color to your styled component:

```
  return (
    <Header color={scrollY > 1}>
      <h1>Header!</h1>
    </Header>
  )
```

To change several properties at once, you can import {css} from styled components:

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

// Define a pure group of css properties
const blueLook= css`
    background-color: #0000ff;
    color: #fff;
`

// Reuse blueLook inside a styled component
const Header = styled.header`
  ${props => props.color && blueLook}
`;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Instead of passing the `color` as a `prop`, is there no way of doing the if statement within the styled component itself? For example: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/building-a-reusable-component-system-with-react-js-and-styled-components-4e9f1018a31c

Comment: Yes you can do that as well: ${props => props.scrollY > 1 && blueLook}   Of course you need to pass scrollY to Header:  <Header scrollY={scrollY} ...

Comment: Oh ok, makes sense. What if I wanted to keep the if statment inside of my `handleScroll` method(like I have it in my question)? I'm trying to see my options :)

Comment: const [color, setColor] = useState(false);   then   
handleScroll() { setColor(window.pageYOffset > 1) }

Comment: Thanks! Works great

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach to the problem. 
Use the `handleScroll` function to set the value of the scrollY variable. 
 Like: 
`function handleScroll() {
    setScrollY(window.pageYOffset);
  }`

Also, since the `window.pageYOffset` will be a `number` so keep the initialState of scrollY to be `0`. 
Like: 
`const [scrollY, setScrollY] = React.useState(0);`

Now send scrollY as a prop to the `Header` component and use this to change the `background-color` and other properties of the component like `color`, `font-size`, etc. 
 Complete solution can be found on my forked version of the code-sandbox. 
 Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/change-styled-component-styling-based-on-windowpageyoffset-y46nj?file=/src/App.tsx 
 Website: https://y46nj.csb.app/

Comment: Thank you, this works well too but HermitCrab managed to answer first so it's only fair I accept his answer :)

Comment: No issues with that ;-) I was working on sandbox so it took me more time.